# How can I merge 2 .ts file in iOS

Tags: ios, http-live-streaming

I have 1 master playlist m3u8 file which has following text inside.

EXTM3U #EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio-0",NAME="Default",AUTOSELECT=YES,DEFAULT=YES,URI="**audio.m3u8**" #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=968000,RESOLUTION=640x360,CODECS="avc1.42001e,mp4a.40.2", AUDIO="audio-0"
**video.m3u8**

After downloading **audio.m3u8** I found there are many .ts file information with the same name is mentioned containing with different byte range information #EXT-X-BYTERANGE:272976@0,....,#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:2737273@74747. I have download 1 segment file from the list which name is **audio.ts**.

Again I download **video.m3u8** which has also contained may .ts file info inside it with same name with different byte range value like

EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1010500@0
video.ts,....,#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:23423@5445
video.ts

My problem in master playlist..

Should I need to download all defined Audio file of m3u8 format and Video file of m3u8 containing with URL value.

From media playlist..
There are many .ts file is given with different byte range which one I should to download for respective video segment file. What is the concept of connect between audio.ts and video.ts.

If suppose I have downloaded both file so how will I merge both audio.ts and video.ts file to play in media player. I am writing code in iOS.

Problem 1.

How will I know which audio file is related with which video file. (I think by Type=Audio is defined for audio file and in video.m3u8 I can map by the Audio tag. Am I correct?).

Problem 2.

How will I merge 2 different audio.ts and video.ts so I can play appropriately in Media playlist of iOS.